# jQuery animate on Wordpress content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have been trying to make it so that when you click the thumbnail image of a post, the content is animated down in a div. If you click another div, the content animates back up and then animates back down with the new content. The content is to be shown in the div theContainer.

Currently it is doing nothing, but I am fairly sure it is close just have made a silly mistake somewhere that I haven't seen.

Live: http://www.mathewhood.com/sitefiles
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YpHCq/

N.B. `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` - Displays the post thumbnail (defined when creating the post in WP)
`<?php the_title(); ?>` - Displays the title of the post
`<?php the_content(); ?>` - Displays the content of the post

Comment: You cannot run ``php`` content on jsfiddle! Is just ok to say where are you stuck, no one want up-votes for nothing ... I think you should be penalized only for thinking of that! Maybe you can set a bounty ... think about your options next time!

Comment: It was more just to show how the loop was working, rather than posting the straight html and then having people not understand things I referred to etc.

I just know that a lot of people here are only in it for the upvotes, and if they do help me along my way I am more than happy to give them. I wasn't saying I would give them to anyone haha.

My issue is in getting the content to display and the jQuery to animate it.

Comment: maybe they are here for the upvotes, for me stackoverflow is another PHP, Javascript, HTML book! I learn every day from my answers and other peoples answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple thing to do, using the following jQuery as a start:

```
$(thumb-nail).click(function(){
   $('.down').slideUp("fast").removeClass('down');
   $(this).parent().find(stuff-to-hide).slideDown("fast").addClass('down');
});
```

Check my working example here - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/byWwk/

Comment: This isn't quite what I want. I would like the content to appear above in the div theContent as I said :)

Also it has to be compatible with the wordpress loop of content.

Comment: This would be compatible with the wordpress loop, you'll just have to tweak it to use the correct ids/classes. This was aimed to be a step in the right direction not the definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out the pieces of php that are contained within your jQuery as they look to be whats causing the page to run incorrectly. I would also change the name of the var from $container to something more distinctive.